# Difference between lists direct assignment and slice assignment

Tags: python-3.x, list, slice

I have:

```py
def reverseString(self, s: List[str]) -> None:
    s[:] = s[::-1] # Works
```

... and

```py
def reverseString(self, s: List[str]) -> None:
    s = s[::-1]    # Doesn't work
```

Where `s` is a list of characters lets say `s = ["k","a","k","a","s","h","i"]`

While doing a question on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-string/) it rejected when I used `s = ...` but accepted when I used `s[:] = ...` and also it was written that *DO NOT RETURN ANYTHING* but `return s.reverse` also worked.

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? it little bit unclear.

Comment: yeah sure, [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-string/) try this question first use s = s[::-1] then use s[:] = s[::-1] they both work the same on my local machine but on the leetcode editor on gets accepted and the other is rejected. So, I want to know the difference between these two. @GiorgiImerlishvili

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bit complex and requires two explanations.

First, a python function argument act as label on the passed object. For example, in the following code, `arg` is the local label (/name) attached to the initial list. When the label `arg` is re-used, for example by attaching it to a new object (`17`), the original list is not reachable anymore within function `f`.

On the other hand, outside of `f`, the list labeled `L` is still here, untouched:

```py
def f(arg):
    arg = 17
    print(arg) # 17

L = ['a', 'list']
f(L)
print(L) # ['a', 'list']
```

That explains why the following function doesn't reverse your list in place:

```py
def reverse_list(arg):
    arg = arg[::-1]
    print(arg) # ['list', 'a']

L = ['a', 'list']
reverse_list(L)
print(L) # ['a', 'list']
```

This function simply attach the label `arg` to a new list (that is indeed equal to the reversed list).

Secondly, the difference between `arg[:] = ...` and `arg = ...` is that the first will modify the content of the list (instead of attaching the label `arg` to a new object). This is the reason why the following works as expected:

```py
def alt_reverse_list(arg):
    arg[:] = arg[::-1]

L = ['a', 'list']
alt_reverse_list(L)
print(L) # ['list', 'a']
```

In this second example we say that the list has been **mutated** (modified in place). Here is a [detailed explanation on slice assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4729334/1720199)

For the same reason, calling `arg.reverse()` would have worked.

#### Identifying objects

Using the [id()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function can help figure out what is going on with the argument in the first example (where we don't mutate the list but affect a new value):

```py
def reverse_list(arg):
    print("List ID before: ", id(arg)) 
    arg = arg[::-1]
    print("List ID after: ", id(arg)) 

L = ['a', 'list']
print("Original list ID: ", id(L)) 
reverse_list(L)
print("Final list ID: ", id(L))
```

Which will print something like:

```
Original list ID:  140395368281088
List ID before:    140395368281088
List ID after:     140395368280447    <--- intruder spotted
Final list ID:     140395368281088
```

Here we can clearly see that after calling `arg = arg[::-1]` the object we are manipulating under the name `arg` is not the same. This shows why the function doesn't have any (side) effect.